# How to I customize certain text in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, d3.js

I have some code where I'm adding an asterisk to the end of a template literal in d3js. I want to be able to customize the size and color of the asterisk independent of the variable. Here is my code.

```
svg.selectAll('.text')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
      .attr('class', d => {
        const shortName = getChannelShortName(d.name).toLowerCase();
        const channelEnabled = disabledChannels.includes(shortName);
        return !channelEnabled ? 'label x-axis-conversion-rate' : 'label x-axis-conversion-rate-disabled'
      })
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('x', d => xScaleBottom(d.name) + (d.subsetValue > 9 ? 45 : 45))
      .attr('y', d => -50)
      .text(d => {
        const shortName = getChannelShortName(d.name).toLowerCase();
        const channelEnabled = disabledChannels.includes(shortName);
        return !channelEnabled ? `${d.conversationRate}%` : `${d.conversationRate}%*`
      });
```

On `${d.conversationRate}%*`, I'd like to get control of this asterisk and  change the size and color of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an svg `tspan` to set font size and color for text within svg `text` elements:

> Inside a  element, text position, text properties, and font properties can be adjusted with with the  element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan))

You can either append the tspan with the text using `selection.append("text").html(string)` where the string is something like `text <tspan font-size="10" fill="orange">text</tspan>`.

Or you can chain two appends together: one to append and set the text, and one to add a tspan to the text (since your tspan will fall at the end of the text):

```
selection.append("text")
 .text(d=>d.someText)
 .filter(function(d) { return d.doesElementNeedAsterisk })
 .append("tspan")
 .text("*");
```

The latter option is demonstrated below:

```js
var data = [
  {text1:"text1",color:"steelblue",size:"30px",asterisk:true},
  {text1:"text2",color:"crimson",size:"40px",asterisk:true},
  {text1:"text3",asterisk:false},
 ];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");
  
svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")             // add text elements
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", (d,i)=> i* 50+50)
  .text(d=>d.text1)          // set the text
  .attr("font-size",20)
  .filter(function(d) {      
    return d.asterisk;       // filter for values that show asterisks
  })
  .append("tspan")           // append a tspan to these text elements
  .text("*")
  .attr("fill", d=>d.color)  // set color
  .attr("font-size",d=>d.size);  // set font size.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx. I was able to get working using the second method